# SAS VA Merge two tables (using GUI)

Tags: sql, merge, sas

Im trying to merge two tables together into one, using the SAS VA user interface. But I only have the option to join (left,right,inner,full). Is this just not possible through the GUI?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SAS VA Data Builder utilizes SQL queries.
So no data-step like merging. Using a Full-Join, or if you have a leading table a Left-Join on this table, will give you the same results as merging with a by statement.

Connect both tables in the GUI using all relevant IDs, or just edit the code yourself in the code-pane.

Edit:
If you want to append data in the VA Data Builder: This is not done in the query. You directly right-click the base table in the in-memory library and choose the append option.

Comment: But if I make a full-join, it says it must have at least 1 column from each table I join. So a.id and b.id. But I want just a 'union all' on id. Maybe it's what SAS calls Append in the system

Comment: You are right, that is called an Append. You do not need to make a query for that. Just right click on your base table in the library and choose append. Make certain you use the in-memory tables.

Comment: Thanks for the help, now its a total other import isse im having.. localizedMessage = "com.sas.lasr.LASRException: ERROR: Failed to derive a formatted value. (errorCode=GENERIC_EXCEPTION, params=null)" .. got no idea what it means xD

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data prep runs on sql, but it doesn't have to. In theory, you can hack the code in data prep to accomplish what you want. First, create a "dummy" query in data prep by pulling any dataset into the design tab (use one from the same library as the others just to make it simple. you could even use one of the two you have selected already), select a column or two to produce results, go to the "outputs" tab and give it the actual name you want it to have in the end. Then click on the "code" tab. You'll see some pre-populated code. Down at the bottom you'll see a proc sql statement querying the dataset and pulling in the columns you selected followed by the code to drop any existing datasets by that name and then a data step to create the table in the lasr library. will look something like this, i called my output testtable_01...

```
proc sql noprint;
create table TEMP_LASR_VIEW_0 as 
SELECT
    library.column_1 length=8 format=16. AS column_1,
    library.column_2 length=8 format=10. AS column_2 
FROM
    library.table;
quit;
/* Drop existing table */
%vdb_dt(LASRLIB.testtable_01);
data LASRLIB.testtable_01 (   );
set TEMP_LASR_VIEW_0 (  );
run;
```

Now preview the results of the query (just to make sure it will work, which it should because it's a simple select statement). Next you'll save the query. This will generate the last piece of code you need... the registertable macro. This will create the reposid and tableid assigned to the output tablename you have it at the start. should look something like this..

```
/* Synchronize table registration */
%registerTable(
 LIBRARY=%nrstr(/Shared Data/SAS Visual Analytics/Public/Visual Analytics Public LASR)
, REPOSID=%str(A5UHNO19)
, TABLEID=%str(A5UHN019.BF003CB7));
```

Now that you have this piece of code you can click the "unlock for manual editing" button (looks like a little padlock at the top left of the code window). Once you click it there is no turning back. If you screw up you'll have to start from scratch. But now you'll be able to modify the code. Replace the proc sql with whatever code you want to merge the two datasets you actually want to use. for example.

```
DATA TEMP_LASR_VIEW_0;  
MERGE library.TABLE_01  
      library.TABLE_02;  
BY COLUMN_01;  
RUN;  
/* Drop existing table */
%vdb_dt(LASRLIB.testtable_01);
data LASRLIB.testtable_01 (   );
set TEMP_LASR_VIEW_0 (  );
run;
/* Synchronize table registration */
%registerTable(
 LIBRARY=%nrstr(/Shared Data/SAS Visual Analytics/Public/Visual Analytics Public LASR)
, REPOSID=%str(A5UHNO19)
, TABLEID=%str(A5UHN019.BF003CB7));
```

Now save the query and run it. Again, in theory this should work. Might need to tweak it a bit. Will probably take a few attempts before getting it perfect.